# Why do Linux split the select partition into /live and /home?

Tags: fedora, partition

When I' installing Fedora(Using automatic partitioning) on a ~140 GB unallocated space, it creates the following partitions:

[image: 808]

And what it seems like, I'm only able to use the `/home` partition(For personal files, installations etc). So I have only 73.4 GB to use for personal use, which is too small. I also did this on my laptop which has a total of 500 GB disk space, turns out there I also got 73.4 GB to use, and the rest ~400GB is unreachable for me.

What is the `/root` partition even used for? And why does it need that kind of space? Can someone explain this for me in a comprehensive way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partition labeled `…/root` here is `/`, the root of your filesystem hierarchy. That would be where installed programs go, as well as global configuration files.

Then `…/home` is where user home directories go, so it's where your personal documents and data, and user-local configurations will go.

For more information about how the filesystem hierarchy is divided, see [the FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

"Using automatic partitioning" is the key phrase. At present:

- 8.5GB is reserved for swap when you run out of RAM. This would usually be calculated from your RAM space.
- Half the rest is allocated to personal files for all users.
- The other half is allocated to Linux. Typically the boot and kernel,
  bin, etc, lib, opt, sbin, sys, tmp, usr, var. That's for all the
  system software, logs, workfiles, and anything else you install from
  repositories.

Your 1TB SSD has around 840 GB unreserved space. You can mark that as one or more partitions (choosing your own sizes), and you can install a File System in each of those partitions.

You can also put personal files in there, and do mounts and links so they appear as extensions to your /home directory. That's often preferable to having one huge partition. You can put alternative distros of Linux in them, or reserve a whole partition for a database, or whatever fits in with what you want from the machine. You haven't lost anything, you just have the opportunity to have more control over it.